# None error when comparing words using the lenght of themselves

Tags: python, otree

I am trying to place a restriction on the minimum number of characters that a subject can use in a form field using `Otree`. I want that if the subjects put a name that is less than 4 characters long, the application shows them an error that says they must write a longer word.

I am using `len` but I am getting the following error:

```
'NoneType' has no len()
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong in the code and help me fix it?

This is my pages.py code.

```
class Consentimiento(Page):

    form_model = 'player'
    form_fields = ['consentimiento', 'consentimienton',]

    def consentimiento_error_message(self, value):
        print('El nombre es', value)
        if len(self.player.consentimiento)) < Constants.number:
            return 'Por favor en el campo de nombre debe poner mínimo 4 letras'
```

This is my `models.py` code

```
consentimienton =  models.StringField( max_length=50 )
```

Comment: what is this? self.player.consentimiento Also, consentimiento and consentimienton are easy to mix

Comment: self.player.consentimiento is a empty stringField where the people put their names.

Comment: Are you sure it is of type stringField? Try to print out the type of `self.player.consentimiento`, then check if it is a compatible type of `len()`

Comment: Yes it is, I defined it in the models.py

Answer (score 0):

I noticed several errors in your working example.

- `len(self.player.consentimiento)` is checking the data, not the input provided by the user. You should replace it with `len(value)`. (Also mind the extra paranthesis)
- You are using `fieldname_error_message(self,value)` function. This should be defined:

  - for the field, not for the page.
  - in `models.py` under your model, not in `pages.py`.

So in the end you should have the following in `models.py`:

```
# Don't forget to define number field in Constants

class Player(BasePlayer):
    consentimienton =  models.StringField( max_length=50 )

    def consentimienton_error_message(self, value):
        print('El nombre es', value)
        if len(value) < Constants.number:
            return 'Por favor en el campo de nombre debe poner mínimo 4 letras'
```

and this in your `pages.py`:

```
class Consentimiento(Page):
    form_model = 'player'
    form_fields = ['consentimienton']
```